# Boto3 and AWS RDS: properly wait for database creation from snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

I have a following code in my Lambda (Python and Boto3):

```
    rds.restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot(
        DBSnapshotIdentifier=snapshot_name,
        DBInstanceIdentifier=db_id,
        DBInstanceClass=rds_instance_class,
        VpcSecurityGroupIds=secgroup,
        DBSubnetGroupName=rds_subnet_groupname,
        MultiAZ=False,
        PubliclyAccessible=False,
        CopyTagsToSnapshot=True
    )


    waiter = rds.get_waiter('db_instance_available')
    waiter.wait(DBInstanceIdentifier=db_id)

# some other operation that expects that DB is up and running.
```

The waiter was added as an attempt to properly wait for DB. However, it looks like the waiter times out.

What would be the correct waiter to use in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try setting `waiter.config.delay` and/or `waiter.config.max_attempts`.

```
waiter = rds.get_waiter('db_instance_available')
waiter.config.delay = 123 # this is in seconds
waiter.config.max_attempts = 123
waiter.wait(DBInstanceIdentifier=db_id)
```

OR

```
waiter = rds.get_waiter('db_instance_available')
waiter.wait(
    DBClusterIdentifier=db_id
    WaiterConfig={
        'Delay': 123,
        'MaxAttempts': 123
    }
)
```

> WaiterConfig (dict) A dictionary that provides parameters to control
> waiting behavior.
>
> Delay (integer) The amount of time in seconds to wait between
> attempts. Default: 30
>
> MaxAttempts (integer) The maximum number of attempts to be made.
> Default: 60

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your waiter is actually checking the existing db and seeing that it's available before the status can update on the previous command to restore the snapshot?